# How to select sublists faster in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My question sounds more general, but I have a specific example. I have a list of data in form:

```
plotDataAll={{DateList1, integerValue1}, {DateList2, integerValue2}...}
```

The dates are sorted chronologically, that is `plotDataAll[[2,1]]` is a more recent time then `plotDataAll[[1,1]]`. 

I want to create plots of specific periods, 24h ago, 1 week ago, etc. For that I need just a portion of data. Here's how I got what I wanted:

```
mostRecentDate=Max[Map[AbsoluteTime, plotDataAll[[All,1]]]];
plotDataLast24h=Select[plotDataAll,AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]>(mostRecentDate-86400.)&];
plotDataLastWeek=Select[plotDataAll,AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]>(mostRecentDate-604800.)&];
plotDataLastMonth=Select[plotDataAll,AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]>(mostRecentDate-2.592*^6)&];
plotDataLast6M=Select[plotDataAll,AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]>(mostRecentDate-1.5552*^7)&];
```

Then I used `DateListPlot` to plot the data. This becomes slow if you need to do this for many sets of data. 
What comes to my mind, if I could find the index of first element in list that satisfies the date condition, because it's chronologically sorted, the rest of them should satisfy the condition as well. So I would have:

```
plotDataLast24h=plotDataAll[[beginningIndexThatSatisfiesLast24h;;Length[plotDataAll]]
```

But how do I get the index of the first element that satisfies the condition?
If you have a faster way to do this, please share your answer. Also, if you have a simple, faster, but sub-optimal solution, that's fine too.

EDIT: 
Time data is not in regular intervals.

Comment: Can use Position[] with a setting to get only the first one. Also if you do this from longest sublist to shortest, you can truncate at each step so that subsequent ones work with smaller lists.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of this. I don't understand patterns well.

Comment: @Daniel, Position[] can be made to return only the first position but I assume (based on timing results) it still checks the entire list. Is there a way to genuinly make MMA stop evaluation of inbuilt functions? The only example that comes to mind is If[] with a long list of && conditions which will terminate on the first `False`.

Comment: @enedene, a pattern based check would be _?(# > val&). E.g. `Position[plotDataAll,_(AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]>(mostRecentDate-86400.)&)]` (I think).

Comment: @Timo I did not consider that it might check the entire list (I've not tested it). I'd guess Scan with Return or Throw could be made to do a short-circuit if Position is reluctant to do so.

Comment: @Daniel, I get a linear time-list length correlation and no time dependence on whether Position[] has to "find" the first, middle or last element in any given list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is at regular intervals you should be able to know how many elements constitute a day, week, etc. and use `Part`.

```
plotDataAll2[[knownIndex;;-1]]
```

or more specifically if the data was hourly:

```
plotDataAll2[[-25;;-1]]
```

would give you the last 24 hours. If the spacing is irregular then use `Select` or `Pick`. Date and time functions in Mma are horrendously slow unfortunately. If you are going to do a lot of date and time calculation better to do a conversion to `AbsoluteTime` just once and then work with that. You will also notice that your `DateListPlot`s render much faster if you use `AbsoluteTime`.

```
plotDataAll2=plotDataAll;
plotDataAll2[[All,1]]=AbsoluteTime/@plotDataAll2[[All,1]];
mostRecentDate=plotDataAll2[[-1,1]]
```

On my computer `Pick` is about 3 times faster but there may be other improvements you can make to the code below:

```
selectInterval[data_, interval_] := (tmp = data[[-1, 1]] - interval; 
  Select[data, #[[1]] > tmp &])

pickInterval[data_, interval_] := (tmp = data[[-1, 1]] - interval; 
  Pick[data, Sign[data[[All, 1]] - tmp], 1])
```

So to find data within the last week:

```
Timing[selectInterval[plotDataAll2, 604800]]
Timing[pickInterval[plotDataAll2, 604800]]
```

Comment: Data is not in regular intervals and all sets of data have different time frames, I'll add that to the post.

Comment: In that case `Pick` is your best option as above.

Comment: Good points about AbsoluteTime, I was not aware that DateListPlot can plot from AbsoluteTime, that's why I haven't used it. I've used your pickInterval function, overall a great improvement, and I've also learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: I should add that the advantages of using `Pick` would normally be even greater, at least another order of magnitude, but we don't get that because date lists are not packed.

Comment: @enedene, yes one of the reasons `DateListPlot` is slow is that it converts date lists to absolute time so if you already have your data in absolute time the plots will render faster.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you want to avoid is checking all the values in the data table. Since the data is sequential you can just start checking from the back and stop when you have found the correct index.

Schematically:

```
tab = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
i = j = Length@tab;
While[tab[[i]] > 5, --i]; 
tab[[i ;; j]]
-> {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

sustitute `> 5` for whatever you want to check for. I didn't have time to test this right now but in your case, e.g.,

```
maxDate=AbsoluteTime@plotDataAll[[-1,1]]; (* no need to find Max if data is sequential*)

i24h = iWeek = iMonth = iMax = Length@plotDataAll;
While[AbsoluteTime@plotDataAll[[i24h,1]] > maxDate-86400.,--i24h];
While[AbsoluteTime@plotDataAll[[iWeek,1]] > maxDate-604800.,--iWeek];
While[AbsoluteTime@plotDataAll[[iMonth,1]] > maxDate-2.592*^6.,--iMonth];
While[AbsoluteTime@plotDataAll[[i6Month,1]] > maxDate-1.5552*^7.,--i6Month];
```

Then, e.g.,

```
DateListPlot@plotDataAll[[i24h;;iMax]]
```

If you want to start somewhere in the middle of `plotDataAll` just use a `While` to first find the starting point and set `iMax` and `maxDate` apropriately.

For large data sets this may be one of the few instances where a loop construct is better than MMA's inbuilt functions. That, however, may be my own ignorance and if anyone here knows of a MMA inbuilt function that does this sort of "stop when match found" comparison better than `While`.

EDIT: Timing comparisons

I played around a bit with Mike's and my solution and compared it to the OP's method. Here is the toy code I used for each solution

```
tab = Range@1000000;

(* My solution *)
i = j = tab[[-1]];
While[tab[[i]] > j - 24, --i];
tab[[i ;; j]]

(* Mike's solution *)
tmp = tab[[-1]] - 24;
Pick[tab, Sign[tab[[All]] - tmp], 1]

(* Enedene's solution *)
j = tab[[-1]];
Select[tab, # > (j - 24) &]
```

Here are the results (OS X, MMA 8.0.4, Core2Duo 2.0GHz)

[image: Timing differences of solutions]

As you can see, Mike's solution has a definite advantage over enedene's solution but, as I surmised originally, the downside of using inbuilt functions like `Pick` is that they still perform a comparative check on all the element in a list which is highly superfluous in this instance. My solution has constant time due to the fact that no unneccessary checks are made.

Comment: Can you show this working on an actual `DateList` please. As it stands it is incomplete (plus it is has a syntax error).

Comment: ok I think I've figured out the typos. Should be `plotDataAll[[iWeek, 1]]]` etc. I tested this for some microsoft data list length 3000. `While` was faster than `Pick` if you only want the first ~60 points (2% of list) after that `Pick` was better. For list length 1000 `Pick`is faster to get >~25 points etc. So depends on list length and expected number of points in the sampling window.

Comment: Your solution is also faster than my original code. Good point about no need for use of Max. Thank you.

Comment: Although it will be interesting to compare the results when data sets become very large, for now I have only 2 months of data (about 1500 points per data set).

Comment: Thanks Mike for the correction. This was just quickly fired off before heading out to a party so I didn't check that it woked. I believe the general idea of the solution to be sound though.

Comment: Yes, which method to use is very heavily dependent on list length so as the list length increases your method has distinct advantages.

Comment: @Timo, great EDIT! I'll use different solutions for different lengths.